# C# program using NPOI to edit cell values of excel(.xls) not working

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I wrote the below program to edit the cell value of a excel file(.xls) using NPOI , program is running without errors or exception but the value is not getting updated

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Web;
 using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
 using NPOI.XSSF.Model;
 using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
 using NPOI.HSSF.Model;
 using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
 using NPOI.SS.Util;
 namespace Project37
 {
    class Class1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string pathSource = @"C:\Users\mvmurthy\Desktop\abcd.xls";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite); 
            HSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);
            HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)templateWorkbook.GetSheet("Contents");
            HSSFRow dataRow = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(4);
            dataRow.Cells[2].SetCellValue("foo");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            templateWorkbook.Write(ms);
            ms.Close();
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `FileStream` instead of `MemoryStream` to save your modified file, otherwise you're not actually saving changes you've made to the disk.

Also note it's better to surround disposable objects like `FileStream` into `using` statement to be sure this object will be automatically disposed when it is out of scope.

So your code could look like:

```
string pathSource = @"C:\Users\mvmurthy\Desktop\abcd.xls";
HSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook;
HSSFSheet sheet;
HSSFRow dataRow;

using (var fs = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    templateWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);
    sheet = (HSSFSheet)templateWorkbook.GetSheet("Contents");
    dataRow = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(4);
    dataRow.Cells[0].SetCellValue("foo");
}

using (var fs = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    templateWorkbook.Write(fs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Andy Korneyev